# How to create meta package (package of all packages) from local nuget packages?

Tags: asp.net-core

How to create a meta package (package of all packages) like Microsoft.AspNetCore.All in nuget for own libraries?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I have found is to reference individual packages in Directory.Build.targets that were referenced in the meta package.